# How to display JSON object from ID in Angular (7)

Tags: json, typescript, angular7

I am trying to create a CRUD application that works a bit like a blog. I have all of the create, read, update, and delete functions working. I want to display only one object's data **(example: title, description)** based on the ID of the object which is part of the route **(localhost:4200/route/0)**.

I can get the data to display the way I want using `<input [(ngModel)]"articles.title">`, but not using `ngFor` on `<h1>` or any other tag.

app-routing-module.ts

```js
{ path: 'article/:id', component: ArticleComponent}
```

db.json

```
"articleInfo": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Marinara Pasta",
      "category": "Italian",
      "author": "Sample",
      "date": "06/11/2019",
      "description": "A classic Italian dish. Quick, easy, and ready to eat in only 15 minutes.",
      "image": "/assets/sample.png"
    }
]
```

data.service.ts

```js
baseUrl:string = "http://localhost:3000";

getData(id: number): Observable<Data> {
  return this.http.get<Data>(this.baseUrl + '/articleInfo/' + id)
}
```

article.component.ts

```js
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {

  id = this.actRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
  articles: any = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, public actRoute: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router) { }
  loadIdData() {
    return this.dataService.getData(this.id).subscribe(data => {
      this.articles = data;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadIdData();
  }

}
```

article.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let info of articles">
      <h2> {{info.title}} </h2>
      <h6> {{info.description}}</h6>
</div>
```

I get ERROR  and ERROR CONTEXT  in ArticleComponent.ngfactory.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out where I was going wrong. `ngFor` is not the correct way to display one set of data. It is expecting multiple sets and as a result does not display anything on the page. What worked for me was pulling the info from `articles: any = [];` in my `article.component.ts` like so:

```html
<h1> {{articles.id}} </h1>
<h2> {{articles.title}} </h2>
<h6> {{articles.description}} </h6>
```

For a far better explanation of why this works, please see [angular.io documentation on displaying data](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data).

Answer (score 1):

You can update your article.component.ts to:

```
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {
  id;
  articles: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, public actRoute: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.actRoute.snapshot.params['id']
    this.loadIdData();
  }

  loadIdData() {
    this.articles = this.dataService.getData(this.id);
  }

}
```

and article.component.html to:

```
<div *ngFor="let info of articles | async">
  <h2> {{info.title}} </h2>
  <h6> {{info.description}}</h6>
</div>
```

The issue appears to be regarding the way you've declared the id property- `actRoute` is only defined after the `constructor` has run, which happens after the properties of the class are accessed.
So when your `loadIdData` function runs `this.id` is likely undefined. For more info see [Angular Lifecycle Docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Note: the `| async` is just some sugar, and isn't really required. You can retain your code and just update the value of the id in the `constructor` or `ngOnInit`.
Here's an [article explaining the async pipe](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-question-rxjs-subscribe-vs-async-pipe-in-component-templates-c956c8c0c794)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this didn't solve my issue. In my original code, I am able to show the proper data using `<input [(ngModel)]="articles.title">`. Your updated code isn't showing anything with ngFor or ngModel. Could the issue be something else?